# How do I get the checkbox state toggle between the two select boxes?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I have two select boxes which loads contacts and groups of contacts, how do I show one div at a time, switching between them by checking or unchecking the checkbox?
The code below show one at off state and show both two when checked instead of hiding the first one and showing the second one.

code snippet

---

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var checkbox = $('#checker'); 
    var dependent = $('#dependent-box');
    var dependent2 = $('#dependent-box2');
    if (checkbox.attr('checked') !== undefined){
        dependent.show();
        dependent2.hide();
    } else {
        dependent2.show();
        dependent.hide();
    }
    checkbox.change(function(e){
        dependent.toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checker" data-toggle="toggle">
<div id="dependent-box">
    <div class="form-group" > 
        <select class="contact-multiple form-control" multiple="multiple" name="to_sms[]" id="toggle1" style="width: 98%;">
            <option value="Hi">
                Hi
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="dependent-box2">
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <select class="contact-multiple form-control" multiple="multiple" name="to_sms[]" id="toggle1" style="width: 98%;">
            <option value="Hi">
                Hello
            </option>    
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not toggling the second box in your change function.

```
  checkbox.change(function(e){
     dependent.toggle();    
     dependent2.toggle();
  });
```

Comment: OH! Thanks! I got the problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o83Lnybt/ <-- Here is a tab system implemented without using so many variables.  Might be worth taking a look if your code starts getting too complex

Answer (score 0):

check if the checker is checked :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var checkbox = $('#checker'); 
    var dependent = $('#dependent-box');
    var dependent2 = $('#dependent-box2');
    dependent2.hide();
    checkbox.change(function(e){
        if(this.checked){
            dependent.hide();
            dependent2.show();
        }else{
            dependent.show();
            dependent2.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checker" data-toggle="toggle">
<div id="dependent-box">
    <div class="form-group" > 
        <select class="contact-multiple form-control" multiple="multiple" name="to_sms[]" id="toggle1" style="width: 98%;">
            <option value="Hi">
                Hi
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="dependent-box2">
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <select  class="contact-multiple form-control" multiple="multiple" name="to_sms[]" id="toggle1" style="width: 98%;">
            <option value="Hi">
                Hello
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it

Comment: @user1740774 you welcome , if this solved your problem then mark it as answered